# Can Google's analytics script run more than once per page view?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console

Is it possible to artificially inflate page views in Google Analytics, for example by executing the analytics tracker script more than once per page view?

Comment: Why would you want to do this??

Comment: @closetnoc - I don't, but found a client where this had happened.

Comment: I was just curious. Sometimes, when there does not seem to be any good that can come from an idea, someone will surprise you with a clever angle that completely makes sense. I have learned that sometimes, something new comes along and it pays to ask Huh?

Comment: Now I see what you meant by that topic question... That's very weird, but I once seen a case when FF loads same `url(image.png)` twice (even when it's only in one spot in CSS and no references in JS or duplicate objects) and second load completely fails and doesn't display image at all. Encoding with base64 solved the issue and even weirded, when I loaded same script from local `file://` it was loading just once and worked :) Oh it was on an object created by jQuery plug-in. (thought it might be relevant)

Answer (score 3):

Try this command:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', newUrl);
```

It's used mainly for tracking pages/content loaded with AJAX but don't see any reason why it shouldn't work with "artificial inflating". You can also skip `newUrl` parameter.